# Fastest way to insert, if not exist, then get id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, pdo, lastinsertid

There's this table.

```
| id | domain |
```

`id` is the primary key. `domain` is a unique key.

I want to:

1. Insert a new domain, if it doesn't exist already.
2. Get the `id` for that domain.

Now I'm doing it like this:

```
INSERT INTO domains
SET domain = 'exemple.com'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

Then `PDO::lastInsertId()` to get the `id`.

But it's critical that this is as fast as it could, so I though I'd ask: *Can I do this in a better way?*

Comment: The CSS for `ol li code` seems a bit off?

Comment: What is id for ? Is it just used as the primary key (i.e. it is opaque to your application otherwise ?)

Comment: Yes. I use it for a request log, and thought varchar would be expansive for a table with lots of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until someone says otherwise, I'm saying *No, that's the best way*.

Answer (score 1):

This method has a side effect: "The auto increment id increments by one each time the duplicate key is found". 
When the query is run  with exemple.com as the value first time 
it creates the entry. Lets say you repeat that query 13 more times. After that you try with xyz.com you will be surprised to see that instead of auto increment id=2 you get 15.

1 exemple.com
15 xyz.com
25 pqr.com
50 thg.com

Comment: Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: The performance of insert ... on duplicate key update is subjecive. Please read: http://mikefenwick.com/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/